Spring Webclient .toFuture().get() is never executed inside another Mono
Could anybody tell me why Mono.toFuture().get() is not executed inside another Mono exceuting thread reactor-http-nio-*?
I am looking for blocking call, I have used .toFuture().get() instead of .block() to avoid illegalstateexception-block-blockfirst-blocklast
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.Dispatcher;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.RecordedRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

public class ReactiveTest {

  static MockServer server = new MockServer();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    server.setUp();
    WebClient.create("http://localhost:1234/primary")
        .get()
        .exchangeToMono(x -> x.bodyToMono(String.class))
        .subscribe(
            response -> {
              System.out.println("First Mono Executing Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
              try {
                CompletableFuture<String> res =
                    WebClient.create("http://localhost:1234/secondary")
                        .get()
                        .exchangeToMono(x -> x.bodyToMono(String.class))
                        .log()
                        .map(
                            x -> {
                              System.out.println("Second Mono Executing Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
                              return x;
                            })
                        .toFuture();
                System.out.println("Second Mono with .toFuture().get() is never executed!: " + res.get());
              } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
              }
            });
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    server.tearDown();
    System.out.println("Main ended! But Second Mono with .toFuture().get() is never executed after waiting for 10 seconds!");
  }

  static class MockServer {
    final Dispatcher dispatcher =
        new Dispatcher() {

          @Override
          public MockResponse dispatch(RecordedRequest request) throws InterruptedException {

            switch (request.getPath()) {
              case "/primary":
                return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody("{\"hello\":\"primary\"}");
              case "/secondary":
                return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody("{\"hello\":\"secondary\"}");
            }
            return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(404);
          }
        };


    MockWebServer server;
    void setUp() {
      server = new MockWebServer();
      server.setDispatcher(dispatcher);
      try {
        server.start(1234);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

    void tearDown() throws IOException {
      server.shutdown();
    }
  }



<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Though I don't understand it well, calling Schedulers.parallel()) before toFuture().get() looks working and executed in speparate thread.
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .toFuture().get();

Example: below toUpperCase is executed in different ("parallel-*") thread
    Mono.just("red")
            .log()
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .toFuture().get();

But when we use .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()) on a WebClient Mono, still that uses "reactor-http-nio-" not the "parallel-" threads. Strange but makes sense. Since reactor-http-nio scheduler is specifically optimized for handling HTTP requests in a non-blocking manner.
whereas the below works on the same main thread
    Mono.just("red")
            .log()
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .toFuture().get();

.toFuture().get() will work in the below simple case
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    server.setUp();
    try {
      Future res =
          WebClient.create("http://localhost:1234/primary")
              .get()
              .exchangeToMono(x -> x.bodyToMono(String.class))
              .log()
              .map(
                  x -> {
                    System.out.println("First Mono Executing Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
                    return x;
                  })
              .toFuture();
      System.out.println("First Mono with .toFuture().get() is executed!: " + res.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    server.tearDown();
    System.out.println(
        "Main ended! First Mono with .toFuture().get() is executed before waiting for 10 seconds!");
  }


So with all these tries, I would suggest instead of the below blocking call,
Mono.block();

we should use the below, this will be safe blocking method when your application is already running through reactive system threads e.g. org.springframework.statemachine
Mono.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).toFuture().get();


If you have any suggestion, I can quickly verify and confirm you!

But why you want to use .toFuture().get()? Is it some requirement from the actual code? Because otherwise it makes no sense and normal reactor code would work just fine without it.

@IgorArtamonov since I need value i have to block the call. But block() will throw exception mentioned in the ticket due to my code is executed inside mono of framework. So only option i left is defer the blocking execution to another thread.

.get is a block too, b/c you stop and wait for something. But there is no reason in your code to do so, except the outer result which is not controlled by Reactor so you can block there as much as you want (and that's the place where blocking is supposed to be used).

Thanks! @IgorArtamonov, But my interest is inner mono result not the outer mono result. Updated my question, My bad! Sorry.

Your code does not require blocking the reactor threads, so there is no reason to use .get or .block:
Mono<String> result = WebClient.create("http://localhost:1234/primary")
    .get()
    .exchangeToMono(response -> {
        return WebClient.create("http://localhost:1234/secondary")
            .get()
            .retrieve()               
            .toEntity(String.class)
            .map(response -> response.getBody());
    });
    
  
// this code is outside of reactor and you can stop and wait if you want
System.out.println("testResult" + result.block());


OH, I am sorry! I have to update the question. I am interested on the result of inner mono.

The outer Mono result is not required, even I dont think the framework expecting anything. So least bothered.

In this case just remove the line with then(...)

But that will resut in illegalstateexception block blockfirst blocklast

But there is no block in the reactor part. Which line throws this exception?

btw, updated the code to fetch actual string, if that matters

But toEntity is not returning the value, it's Mono again. The problem lies in retrieving the value without blocking the thread. I mean without exception.

Right, it's a Mono. That's what exchangeToMono expects, a Function<ClientResponse, Mono<T>> block and the code returns Mono<String>. Or I'm missing something?

UPD in the example, I've move the .map() to extract actual string to make it returning Mono<String> so it may make a bit more sense. Though the previous version of the code should work the same way
